# Delete .doc duplication during PDF conversion c#

Tags: c#

I currently have a program that merges a folder consisting of word docs into one combined file via user input with a FileBrowserDialog. Once files are selected, a 'combine' button applies the code shown below which sources the folder containing the documents, output location and name of the file created.

```
string fileDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yy");
string fileTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH.mm.ss");
string outcomeFolder = outputFolder;
string outputFileType = ".docx";
string outputFile = "Combined Folder " + fileDate + " @ " + fileTime + outputFileType;
string outputFileName = Path.Combine(outcomeFolder, outputFile);

// Combines the file name, output path selected and the yes / no for pagebreaks. 
MsWord.Merge(sourceFiles, outputFileName, pageBreaker);

// Message displaying how many files are combined. 
MessageBox.Show("A total of " + sourceFiles.Length.ToString() + " documents have been merged", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);}
```

The MsWord referenced calls a separate .CS file which combines the folder components, output name and a boolean to enable page-breaks. The MsWord also automatically saves the word .doc to the user specified location once the contents of the folder are successfully combined. `MsWord.Merge(sourceFiles, outputFileName, pageBreaker);`

The issue i'm wanting to address is, when I enable this check box:

```
if (convert2PDFBox.Checked)
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application officeApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

officeApp.Documents.Open(outputFileName);
outputFileType = ".pdf";
officeApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(outputFileName + outputFileType, WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF);
officeApp.Quit();
```

I want the program to solely create a PDF of the combined folder and not 2 seperate .doc and .PDF files, which it currently does. Since the MsWord.save function is called separately and is essential to the overall function of my program, I was wondering is there a possibility of deleting the initially combined file once conversion of the PDF takes place? ***e.g. "combinedDocument".Delete*** - Essentially allowing the copy to take place however not presenting the user with the initial .doc - only the .PDF

Though the issue is small, I would love to get it addressed and welcome any suggestions or advice with this manner. I can also provide any additional information if needed, thank you.

*tl;dr -* merging program creates an amalgamated Word .doc, which i want to change solely to a PDF when a checkbox is enabled instead of creating a .doc and PDF.

Comment: Instead of .save() what about calling .saveAs()?

Comment: @Duston, when i try "save" instead of "save as" i'm getting an error `no overload for method Save takes 2 arguments` 

any suggestions as to what that fully means?

Comment: **update** got rid of the error, i was required to remove the `outputFileName + outputFileType, WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF` - However now i don't see how the program will convert the .doc to a PDF?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d525b79d-ab45-4173-98d9-17f916c35ed4/save-word-document-as-pdf-using-vba?forum=isvvba  Try that.  I'll bet you had the right idea for .Save() but like the error told you , you can't "Save" to another file type because you're just saving the file you're working on right now.  You have to .SaveAs() instead.  The "No overload for method..." error meant you were trying to call .Save(String, Int) but there is no such animal.  You can only call .Save()

Comment: @duston - thanks for the advice! My code currently has "save as" implemented. The program currently and successfully creates the PDF version of my word doc. My query was that I wanted the program to only produce the PDF (when the checkbox is active) as opposed to producing the word .doc, which is then copied and converted into a PDF, leaving me with 2 files. 1 .doc and 1 .pdf. ideally i'd only like the PDF

Comment: That's what I was going for, instead of calling Save() (which creates the one Word document), call SaveAs() to create directly to the one PDF from the two Word documents.  You shouldn't need the intermediate Word document at all.

Comment: @duston - sorry to sound stupid, but i don't know / see what Save() you are referring to within my code, is it the MsWord.Merge? in which the word document is initially saved? i've been trying to convert the .save in this scenario into PDF but i'm getting similar results were both file outcomes are produced.

Comment: @duston - thank you for the suggestions. i have finally resolved the issue - a brief explanation have been provided in my answer submission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved my issue - What I decided to do was manipulate my existing **MsWord.cs** and create a separate **PDF.cs** call for my main form:

Rather than save the Word .doc when being merged, I instead used: `wordApplication.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(outputFile, Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF);`
 which saved the merged content thus far as a .pdf

This however presented errors with Microsoft Word as I was then prompted to *'Save File As'* due to the merged file never actually being saved in a .Doc / .Docx format

I then altered the closing statement of the call,

`// Close Word application 
wordApplication.Quit(
false, // save changes`

By setting the *'Save Changes'* setting to **False,** it removed the *'Save As'* prompt which allowed the Word doc. to be dismissed without needing to be saved, thus leaving only the initial PDF created. I then applied the two separate File type calls to each checkbox presented, which allowed the user to enable the outcome format of the merged files.

Thank you for the suggestions regarding the issue.